# OBD2 device that connects over cellular data?

Tags: obd-ii, obd

I'm looking to monitor any and all stats of my vehicle. Are there any OBD devices that connect remotely over cellular data, and come with a nice phone app?

I'd like to be able to monitor the car from anywhere, and for the car to be anywhere (I'm not in the car, or even near the car). For example, for rental purposes, or for fleet purposes.

Comment: Wifi or Bluetooth. You choose.

Comment: @zipzit I'd like it to be to be fully remote, so the car can be anywhere, and I can be anywhere else.

Comment: @zipzit I updated my question. :)

Comment: The german Telekom provides services with a device that looks like what you are looking for: https://www.telekom.com/en/media/media-information/archive/carconnect-adapter-transforms-any-car-into-a-hospot-508402 Maybe you can find out what's the actual device that they are using for this. It seems [to be marketed in USA as SyncUP Drive](https://www.t-mobile.com/offers/syncup).

Comment: Do you want location of the vehicle or if johnny's been banging off the redline at every stop light?

Comment: @DatsunZ1 Both, and whatever other info it can provide.

Comment: @trusktr your going to have to pay to play. The money your going to save on potential maintenance and gas is more than full insurance and hiring trustworthy employees. These devices are expensive upfront and also have ongoing costs for fees and cellular connection.

Comment: @DatsunZ1 True, and I'd like to evaluate what that monthly cost may be, but first I'd need to know which devices can do it. The ones that are easy to find don't have a cellular connection.

Comment: Do you want your car to call your cell phone on the network of cellular towers thereby use the cellular data allowance of your cell providers plan?  Or do you want your car to send data to an app on your phone via a Bluetooth connection that is not dependent on the cellular network or a WiFi router ??

Comment: @AlaskaMan  I'd for it to be fully remote so that if I'm hundreds of miles away from the car I know what is being done to the car. So I suppose that would require the car to have its own mobile connection. But as a plan B I don't mind detecting what happened to the car once I reunite with it and view it's history locally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are various devices on the market combining an OBD2 dongle with a small micro controller embedding a SIM card – a web search for "OBD2 SIM card" turns up results from Aliexpress, Ryd, Logpit, Fleetize, and more.

That said, you will probably end up with a much more flexible and less expensive (and probably more reliable solution) using an Android or iOS device that's fixed in the car talking to a BLE OBD2 reader.

Answer (score 0):

An easy option would be to plug a normal cheap elm bluetooth dongle and a normal phone with data plan and use teamviewer for accessing that phone remotely.